# Permission denied: 'dbt_modules'

Tags: python, docker, airflow, dbt

I get this error running dbt deps. Am I missing something in the dockerfile to provide access to dbt_modules? I can't seem to find where it's located or what dbt_modules even is in the documentation. I've provided the code to several yml files. Thanks in advance

Traceback

```
2022-06-07 04:34:59.121970 (MainThread): Running with dbt=0.21.1
2022-06-07 04:34:59.972911 (MainThread): You have an incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed (6.0.1), please install a version that adheres to: 'pyarrow<3.1.0,>=3.0.0; extra == "pandas"'
2022-06-07 04:35:00.477470 (MainThread): running dbt with arguments Namespace(cls=<class 'dbt.task.deps.DepsTask'>, debug=False, defer=None, log_cache_events=False, log_format='default', partial_parse=None, profile=None, profiles_dir='/home/airflow/.dbt', project_dir=None, record_timing_info=None, rpc_method='deps', single_threaded=False, state=None, strict=False, target=None, test_new_parser=False, use_cache=True, use_colors=None, use_experimental_parser=False, vars='{}', warn_error=False, which='deps', write_json=True)
2022-06-07 04:35:00.478141 (MainThread): Tracking: tracking
2022-06-07 04:35:00.478667 (MainThread): Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'start', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0ddcee20>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0ddce6d0>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0de7d130>]}
2022-06-07 04:35:00.479294 (MainThread): Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'end', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0ddcee20>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0ddce6d0>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7f2d0de7d130>]}
2022-06-07 04:35:00.479750 (MainThread): Flushing usage events
2022-06-07 04:35:00.913755 (MainThread): Encountered an error:
2022-06-07 04:35:00.914481 (MainThread): [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dbt_modules'
2022-06-07 04:35:00.916934 (MainThread): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 127, in main
    results, succeeded = handle_and_check(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 205, in handle_and_check
    task, res = run_from_args(parsed)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 258, in run_from_args
    results = task.run()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/task/deps.py", line 46, in run
    system.make_directory(self.config.modules_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/system.py", line 109, in make_directory
    raise e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/system.py", line 103, in make_directory
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dbt_modules'
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  # image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./config/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
    - ./dbt:/opt/airflow/dbt
    - ~/.dbt:/home/airflow/.dbt:ro
    - ./dags:/dags
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
```

dbt_project.yml

```
target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_modules"
  - "dbt_packages"
```

packages.yml

```
packages:
  - package: fishtown-analytics/dbt_utils
    version: 0.6.4
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ${AIRFLOW_BASE_IMAGE}

USER airflow
RUN pip install dbt \ 
                apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure==3.7.0 \
                apache-airflow-providers-snowflake\ 
                riotwatcher \
                pandas
```

Comment: The exception suggests that `dbt_modules` is the name of a folder the program is trying to create somewhere on your disk. It doesn't have permission to create the folder, so that step is failing. I don't know enough about the libraries you're using to judge what that means, really, or how to fix it. But I think the name in the error message is a bit of a red herring, since it's not a Python module that's the problem at all, it's an issue of file system permissions, or maybe the working directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbt creates a `dbt_modules` directory (renamed to `dbt_packages` in [version 1.0](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/migration/versions/upgrading-to-v1.0#renamed-fields-in-dbt_projectyml)) inside your dbt project directory when you run `dbt deps` (which installs dbt packages in your project).

It looks like you're mounting your dbt project directory as a volume. Most likely the user that runs `dbt deps` (as an airflow task) is not authorized to write to that volume.

You may be able to configure the `modules-path` (`packages-install-path` after 1.0) in your `dbt_project.yml` file to write to a local directory instead of the protected volume. [Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/packages-install-path)

Comment: Thanks! Configuring a different module path solved my issue.